# HDF5 C++ with third party filters

Tags: c++, hdf5

I am trying to write C++ code to create an HDF5 dataset with third-party filters listed here: "https://support.hdfgroup.org/services/contributions.html". I created a snappy filter function that can compress as well as decompress the data using the snappy library functions. I was able to write with snappy filter and read from it without any problem. However, when I try to read the data through h5dump, I am not getting any output even though I am using the correct filter ID (32003 for snappy).

I am guessing the problem is that h5dump doesn't have access to my filter function. Is there any way around it? Can I somehow create a library and tell h5dump to get the function from it? Alternatively, since the filter is already registered with the hdfgroup, I guess I can assume there is already an existing implementation of the filter function that h5dump can read. Can I use that in my C++ code for consistency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, since HDF5 version 1.8.11 you can make use of [dynamically loaded filters]
(https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/Advanced/DynamicallyLoadedFilters/HDF5DynamicallyLoadedFilters.pdf).
You basically need to create a shared library of your filter function and make it available to the HDF5 library by puting it in a specific folder (`/usr/local/hdf5/lib/plugin`) or specifying the folder via `HDF5_PLUGIN_PATH`.

As an example you can take a look at the [lzf filter](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/tree/master/lzf) in the h5py repo.

Also take a look at [Blosc](http://www.blosc.org/) which is a meta-compressor for various compression algorithms including snappy.